# Seamless process to obtain test ether from faucet?

Tags: ropsten, kovan

I am unable to successfully "Buy" Ether from a faucet for Ropsten or from Kovan.  Is it me or do most people have issues setting up a testnet using Ropsten and/or Kovan?  Can anyone help me find a way to seamlessly process these faucets (or suggest an alternative)?

I receive this error message: {"error":"[ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{"value":{"code":-32000,"message":"replacement transaction underpriced"}}'"}

As I repeated my efforts, Ropsten's service reported a new message that my IP address has been "greylisted for 24 hours".  Kovan reported a new message "Too many requests created from this IP/limit 5/hr".

I'm using a Brave/Remix/MetaMask chain.

Comment: Ropsten has been deprecated, Goerli is now the only Ethereum supported testnet. If you need any Goerli - https://goerlifaucet.com/.

Answer (score 0):

That is, unfortunately, quite common nowadays.

Fortunately there are multiple faucets out there. One of the better working ones can be found at mycrypto.com, I've been told. They launched it a few months ago.

Another option, especially if you need a lot of Eth, is to simply start mining. This is valid at least in Ropsten, but unsure how the process works for non-PoW networks - it may not be so easy.

Comment: Thank you Lauri.  I'll try mycrypto.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Update to all.  I was finally able to get ETH and LINK tokens from the Kovan faucet by waiting out the time-imposed (6 +/- hour) restrictions on my account, and then resending the requests.  I've given up on Robsten because it just doesn't seem to want to play.